# C++ calling getenv("LINES") or getenv("COLUMNS") runs fine in Xcode, segfaults when run in terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clang

I'm trying to get the window size of my program when its run in terminal. In Xcode, I've edited the scheme so that the `LINES` and `COLUMNS` environmental variables are set for running within Xcode, and it runs fine there. But when I click the executable under Products and try running that within the Terminal, it segfaults. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Does it have anything to do with my `#includes`? Here's my basic code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char* r = getenv("COLUMNS") ;

    cout << r << endl ;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it segfaults in a terminal, it's almost certainly because the environment variable does not exists, hence `r` will be `NULL`. So your program would be better off checking for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char *r = std::getenv ("COLUMNS");
    std::cout << ((r == NULL) ? "?" : r) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Run the following command from a terminal and see what you get:

```
echo "!$COLUMNS!"
```

If it's `!!`, you'll need to figure out how to get the variables set (and exported so that they appear to sub-processes), such as with:

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
export COLUMNS
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out. You were right that `LINES` and `COLUMNS` were not set. Somewhow ~/.bash_profile got messed up when I was playing around with it yesterday, and I think both environment variables weren't set correctly. I edited .bash_profile and now it seems to be working.